# Looking up SKU ID and Instance Details on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am working an an application running on AWS and reporting certain usage data. Is there a way to find out the EC2 instance's SKU ID and details (num. of CPUs, RAM, etc.)? I was looking at the AWS price list API, but it seems that there are multiple possible SKU IDs for an instanceType, because there are some other attributes such as OperatingSystem, reserved vs. on-demand, etc. My questions are:

1. Is the AWS price list API the best choice?
2. What's the minimum set of filters that I need to map to a unique SKU ID?

Comment: You should look for CloudWatch metrics API and instance ID instead (assuming "usage data" means CPU/RAM etc.),

Comment: Are you asking how to find out the resources that are allocated to a particular Instance Type? There is not currently an API call that provides such information, but you can use 3rd-party websites like https://www.ec2instances.info/